# Scheme result of a function

Tags: scheme, racket

I have met the following code in Scheme:

```
(define x! 
  (lambda(x)
    (if (= x 1) 1 (* x (x! (- x 1))))))

(define fact x!)

(define x! (lambda (x) x))
(fact 5)
```

Everything is clear for me until re-defining x! and seeing the result of the function (20).
How can it be explained?.. Why is it 20 and not 5!= 120. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Scheme behaves when you have a redefinition of an identifier is to use `set!` for it.  In your case, if you replace the redefinition with

```
(set! x! (lambda (x) x))
```

then the result will become clearer.

(Note that this is not something that *all* schemes do...)

Comment: what do you mean "not something all schemes do"?

Comment: @newacct: Eli is referring to implementations. I think he means: (Note that not all scheme implementations will use `set!` instead of `define` in the case of a redefinition)

Comment: newacct: It's close to what incrediman said -- in some implementations -- mostly ones where you write code in modules, `define` is only creating a new definition, not mutating an existing one.

Comment: it's defined in the scheme standards. see http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.1

Comment: newacct: Yes, I know that it's defined in some scheme standards.  (R6RS is different.)  That has nothing to do with what I said -- and in fact, since scheme standards are notoriously small, implementations always extend them.  (A module system being the extension in this case.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what's happening:

When you `(define fact x!)`, you aren't permanently linking `fact` to `x!`. You're making `fact` equal to **whatever `x!` is at the time of `fact`'s definition**.

So `(define fact x!)` is actually equivalent to:

```
(define fact
  (lambda(x)
    (if (= x 1) 1 (* x (x! (- x 1))))))
```

Next, you redefine x!:

```
(define x! (lambda (x) x))
```

But that **does not** change `fact` - it only changes `x!`. Next, you do this:

```
(fact 5)
```

---

Here's what the interpreter 'does' next (it may actually do it slightly differently - but only trivially so, and this should at least help you understand the behaviour of your program):

Replacing `fact` with its definition gives:

```
(lambda(x)
    (if (= x 1) 1 (* x (x! (- x 1)))))
```

Replacing `x!` with its *new* definition gives:

```
((lambda(x)
   (if (= x 1)
       1
       (* x 
          (- ((lambda (x)
                x)
              x)
             1))))
 5)
```

...Simplifying gives:

```
((lambda(x)
   (if (= x 1)
       1
       (* x (- x 1))))
 5)
```

...

```
(if (= 5 1)
    1
    (* 5 (- 5 1)))
```

...

```
(if #f
    1
    (* 5 (- 5 1)))
```

...Resolving the conditional and simplifying the substraction gives:

```
(* 5 4)
```

...Which yields 20.

Answer (score 3):

first you define x! to be the way to compute factorial (i.e. (x! 5) = 120).
Then you define fact to be what x! is, which is the same function (i.e. fact = `lambda(x) (if (= x 1)...`
Then you change what x! is the identity.  However, `fact` is still that same function, you didn't change it, but that function references x! internally, so it ends up calling fact (which is the first thing you defined) which calls the identity function.

so `(fact 5)` is the same as:

```
(if (= 5 1) 1 (* 5 (x! (- 5 1))))))
```

which is the same as:

```
(if false 1 (* 5 (x! 4)))
```

which is the same as:

```
(if false 1 (* 5 4))
```

which is the same as:

```
(* 5 4)
```

which is `20`

Comment: Note that in standard scheme you use `#f`, not `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what happens here is the following:

When you do `(x! (- x 1))` inside the original definition of `x!`, you're calling the function named `x!`. So if you change what the name `x!` means, that will affect this call to `x!`.

When you do `(define fact x!)` fact doesn't refer to the name `x!`, but to the current contents of `x!`, i.e. the function you just defined.

Now you change the meaning of the name `x!` and then call `(fact 5)`. This will first invoke the original definition of `x!` (because that's what fact refers to), however when it gets to the call `(x! (- 5 1))`, it invokes the new definition of `x!`, which returns 4, so you get 5*4 = 20.

Comment: "change the meaning of the name `x!`" is actually much simpler than it looks: this meaning is whatever value it points to, and this value is mutated in this example.

Comment: @EliBarzilay: If the value was mutated that would also affect `fact` which points to the same value, wouldn't it?

Comment: sepp2k: No, the value itself is not mutated, which is why `fact` stays the same.  Instead, it's the `x!` *binding* that gets mutated.

Answer (score 0):

One side note: You need to use an environment model to figure it out.Because the answer of questions like that differs in lexical scoping versus dynamic scoping.